# How to combine multiple rows with similar data?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have pandas dataframe / CSV table, where I have retrieved a lot of data and that creates multiple row for same object.

I would like to combine these rows back to single row by combining lowest values from each row. This could be possibly done by using (min). function, but I don't know how.

Data also contains "null" values.

| ID | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| object1 | 16 | null | 19 | 13.7 |
| object1 | 17 | 9 | 17 | Nan |
| object1 | 17 | 11 | 15 | NaN |
| object2 | null | null | null | 9.8 |

I am hoping for result like this:

| ID | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| object1 | 16 | 9 | 15 | 13.7 |
| object2 | null | null | null | 9.8 |

I am able to use something like this:

```
df.groupby('ID')['A'].min()
```

But I can't go further from there to write full df again with all other data like column D.

Comment: how about `df.groupby('ID').min()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `groupby` + `first`. `first` is better than `min` in that it supports non-numeric columns (i.e., if you use `df.groupby('ID').min()` you'll get a warning and it will drop some columns):

```
new_df = df.groupby('ID', as_index=False).first()
```

Output:

```
>>> new_df
        ID     A    B     C     D
0  object1  16.0  9.0  19.0  13.7
1  object2   NaN  NaN   NaN   9.8
```

Edit: I guess you can use `min` actually (it was just a problem on my end):

```
new_df = df.groupby('ID', as_index=False).min()
```

Output:

```
>>> new_df
        ID     A    B     C     D
0  object1  16.0  9.0  15.0  13.7
1  object2   NaN  NaN   NaN   9.8
```

Comment: We are closer, would that pick the first numeral, instead of smallest numeral? In column C I would like to see value 15 not 19?

Comment: Okay, check the bottom of the answer. Turns out you *can* use `min`.